# How to determine when Vue has finished updating the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I want to access the inner `<input>` element after it has been created by Vue:

```
<li v-repeat="subtask: subtasks">
    <input v-model="subtask.name" type="text">
</li>
```

However, this code does not work:

```
/* add a new item (that in turn will create a new DOM node) */
subtasks.push({
    name: 'wash the dishes',
    id: 'box-123'
});

/* ... Around now, Vue should get busy creating the new <li> ... */

/* Now the element should exist, but it doesn't */
console.log(document.getElementById('box-123'));
// --> null
```

However, the `getElementById` call comes back empty handed--the node does not exist at that time.

When can I be sure Vue has created / updated the DOM?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Vue batches DOM updates and performs them asynchronously for performance reasons. After a data change, you can use `Vue.nextTick` to wait for the DOM updates to finish:

```
subtasks.push({});
Vue.nextTick(function () {
  // DOM updated
});
```

If you are using it inside a component method where `this` is available (and a reference to the component), you can use:

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
  // DOM updated
});
```

References:

[`Vue.nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

[`vm.$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick)

Answer (score 2):

If vue does not have a callback for this you can use a MutationObserver  listener on the parent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    ...
    });
  },
```